# Running Rspec fails if variables can be passed to a class in Puppet

Tags: testing, rspec, tdd, puppet

**Problem**

If variables can be passed to a Puppet class, e.g.:

```
class module_name (
  $variable='hello_world'
) {
  package { 'package_name': }
}
```

and `rspec` is run it fails, i.e.:

```
[user@host module_name]$ rspec
...............................FFFFFFFFFFFF..........................................

Failures:

  1) opsview should contain Class[module_name]
     Failure/Error: it { should contain_class('module_name') }
     Puppet::Error:
       Error from DataBinding 'hiera' while looking up 'module_name::variable': 
       FileSystem implementation expected Pathname, got: 'Hash' on node host
     # /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource.rb:393:
         in `rescue in lookup_with_databinding'
     # /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource.rb:387:
         in `lookup_with_databinding'
     # /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/resource.rb:381:
         in `lookup_external_default_for'
```

*Main issue*

```
Error from DataBinding while looking up FileSystem implementation expected Pathname, 
got: 'Hash' on node
```

**Configuration**

*Versions*

```
[vagrant@vm-one opsview]$ puppet --version
3.7.5
[vagrant@vm-one opsview]$ rspec --version
3.2.2
```

*Spec_helper*

```
[vagrant@vm-one opsview]$ cat spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'rspec-puppet'
require 'hiera-puppet-helper'

fixture_path = File.expand_path(File.join(__FILE__, '..', 'fixtures'))

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.module_path = File.join(fixture_path, 'modules')
  c.manifest_dir = File.join(fixture_path, 'manifests')
  c.hiera_config = '/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml'
end

at_exit { RSpec::Puppet::Coverage.report! }
```

**Attempt**

1. According to [this Q&A](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/7yRiPIOh6L0/z0EAu64KpWQJ) `hiera-puppet-helper` is causing the
   issue. Rspec-puppet seems to support testing of hiera and
   'hiera-puppet-helper' could be replaced. Ok perhaps this solves the issue, but what is causing the issue?
2. [This post](https://gist.github.com/msapariya/eca9f77c9f560f8a0e57) contains the same issue, but not a solution to solve
   the issue
3. [This post](https://www.mail-archive.com/puppet-users@googlegroups.com/msg54082.html) indicates that removing the class parameters solves the issue, but this class is used by multiple modules and therefore this is not a solution.

Comment: So with `c.hiera_config = '/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml'`, you're telling `rspec-puppet` to use your *productive* Hiera data for testing? Is that not risky?

Comment: rspec-puppet has built in hiera support. no need for `hiera-puppet-helper`. https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet look at the part about hiera integration.

Comment: @FelixFrank It is possible to use a separate hiera.yaml per environment, e.g. /etc/puppet/environments/production/hiera.yaml and /etc/puppet/environments/dev/hiera.yaml? The hieradata is different per environment at the moment and resides in /etc/puppet/environments/production and /etc/puppet/environments/dev

Comment: @ptierno You are right. I am using it at the moment, the issue has been solved and do not use hiera-puppet-helper anymore. I was just curious why hiera-puppet-helper causes the issue. Perhaps you could explain this and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the `hiera_config`, it should be:

```
c.hiera_config = 'spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml'
```

assuming that you have directory structure like:

```
  \spec
    \fixtures
      \hiera
        hiera.yaml
        default.yaml
```

and `hiera.yaml`:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - '%{::clientcert}'
  - default
:yaml:
  :datadir: './spec/fixtures/hiera'
```

The `hiera-puppet-helper` gem is indeed not required, in fact it shouldn't be there. I'd recommend generating module structure using [Garethr's skeleton](https://github.com/garethr/puppet-module-skeleton) which already contains working setup for Hiera and can save you a lot of time.